# R About Array replacement

Tags: arrays, r, replace

```
ordered_use
                                                                        2 UNIT CONVERTED DWELLING 
                                           28706                                               51 
                                 2 UNIT DWELLING                                          2 UNITS 
                                              99                                               44 
                                 3 UNIT DWELLING                                        APARTMENT 
                                              31                                             4733 
                                      APARTMENT                                    APARTMENT BLDG 
                                              38                                               37 
                              APARTMENT BUILDING                                   APARTMENT UNIT 
                                            2042                                               37 
                             APPARTMENT BUILDING                                              APT 
                                              54                                              357 
                                        APT BLDG                                     APT BUILDING 
                                              78                                               49 
                                            APT.                                        APT. BLDG 
                                              41                                               61 
                                   APT. BUILDING                                            ARENA 
                                              35                                               67 
                                            BANK                                    BOWLING ALLEY 
                                             302                                              267 
                                        BUNGALOW                                   CAR DEALERSHIP 
                                              85                                               62 
                                          CHURCH                                             CLUB 
                                              94                                               40 
                                         COLLEGE                                       COMMERCIAL 
                                             196                                              410 
                          COMMERCIAL/RESIDENTIAL                                 COMMUNITY CENTRE 
                                              56                                              131 
                                  COMMUNITY HALL                                            CONDO 
                                              31                                              223 
                                     CONDOMINIUM                               CONVERTED DWELLING 
                                              42                                               42 
                                 CONVERTED HOUSE                        CONVERTED HOUSE - 2 UNITS 
                                             149                                              124 
                       CONVERTED HOUSE - 3 UNITS                        CONVERTED HOUSE (2 UNITS) 
                                              56                                               35 
                         CONVERTED HOUSE 2 UNITS                         CONVERTED HOUSE, 2 UNITS 
                                              38                                               84 
                        CONVERTED HOUSE, 3 UNITS                                          DAYCARE 
                                              42                                               31 
                                   DENTAL OFFICE                                   DETACHED - SFD 
                                              87                                              513 
               DETACHED - SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING                                   DETACHED HOUSE 
                                              97                                              130 
                                    DETACHED SFD                                           DUPLEX 
                                             190                                              145 
                               ELEMENTARY SCHOOL                                        FIRE HALL 
                                             859                                               41 
                                  FITNESS CENTRE                                     FUNERAL HOME 
                                              48                                               36 
                                          GARAGE                                      GAS STATION 
                                              63                                              130 
                                   GROCERY STORE                                       GROUP HOME 
                                              51                                               45 
                                      HAIR SALON                                HOME FOR THE AGED 
                                              46                                               49 
                                        HOSPITAL                                            HOTEL 
                                             971                                              215 
                                           HOUSE                                              IND 
                                            1249                                              219 
                                      INDUSTRIAL                                      INDUSTRIAL  
                                            1725                                               35 
                             INDUSTRIAL BUILDING                         INDUSTRIAL MANUFACTURING 
                                              51                                               91 
                            INDUSTRIAL WAREHOUSE                                    INSTITUTIONAL 
                                              61                                               48 
                                             LAB                                       LABORATORY 
                                              56                                               46 
                                         LIBRARY                          LONG TERM CARE FACILITY 
                                              91                                               74 
                                     LUMBER YARD                                    MANUFACTURING 
                                              53                                               55 
                                  MEDICAL OFFICE                                        MIXED USE 
                                             247                                              539 
                                      MIXED USE                            MIXED USE (COMMERCIAL) 
                                              40                                               34 
                              MIXED USE (RETAIL)                               MIXED USE BUILDING 
                                              74                                              297 
              MIXED USE BUILDING/NON RESIDENTIAL                                MIXED USE NON RES 
                                              37                                               93 
                      MIXED USE NON RES (RETAIL)                          MIXED USE RES & NON RES 
                                              52                                               59 
                                       MIXED-USE                                       MULTI UNIT 
                                             202                                               54 
                             MULTI UNIT BUILDING                                        MULTI USE 
                                              70                                              381 
                              MULTI USE, NON RES                                MULTI USE/NON RES 
                                             134                                               36 
                       MULTI USE/NON RESIDENTIAL                                    MULTIPLE UNIT 
                                              49                                              149 
                          MULTIPLE UNIT BUILDING                                           MUSEUM 
                                              40                                               40 
                                             N/A                                             NONE 
                                             650                                              264 
                                       NOT KNOWN                                     NURSING HOME 
                                              58                                               55 
                                             OFF                                           OFFICE 
                                             181                                             9698 
                                         OFFICE                                        OFFICE BLD 
                                              50                                               46 
                                 OFFICE BUILDING                                     OFFICE SPACE 
                                             177                                               39 
                                   OFFICE/RETAIL                                 OFFICE/WAREHOUSE 
                                              36                                               95 
                                         OFFICES                                            OTHER 
                                              63                                               54 
                                            PARK                                   PARKING GARAGE 
                                             137                                              149 
                                     PARKING LOT                            PERSONAL SERVICE SHOP 
                                             126                                               49 
                                PLACE OF WORSHIP                                   POLICE STATION 
                                             516                                               34 
                                    PROF. OFFICE                                     RECREATIONAL 
                                              65                                               46 
                                   REPAIR GARAGE                                              RES 
                                              91                                              242 
                                     RESIDENTIAL                                RESIDENTIAL - SFD 
                                             488                                              561 
                               RESIDENTIAL CONDO                                             REST 
                                              39                                               46 
                                      RESTAURANT                            RESTAURANT > 30 SEATS 
                                            1074                                               42 
                RESTAURANT GREATER THAN 30 SEATS                    RESTAURANT LESS THAN 30 SEATS 
                                             145                                               69 
                       RESTAURANT UNDER 30 SEATS                RESTAURANT, GREATER THAN 30 SEATS 
                                              47                                               42 
                                             RET                                           RETAIL 
                                              81                                             4001 
                                         RETAIL                                       RETAIL MALL 
                                              46                                               61 
                                    RETAIL PLAZA                                     RETAIL STORE 
                                              96                                              796 
                                   RETAIL/OFFICE                               RETAIL/RESIDENTIAL 
                                              32                                               99 
                                   ROOMING HOUSE                                        ROW HOUSE 
                                              89                                               38 
                                          SCHOOL                                 SECONDARY SCHOOL 
                                             594                                              246 
                                            SEMI                                    SEMI DETACHED 
                                             209                                              218 
                             SEMI DETACHED - SFD           SEMI DETACHED - SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING 
                                             212                                               50 
                               SEMI DETACHED SFD                                    SEMI-DETACHED 
                                              46                                               71 
                             SEMI-DETACHED - SFD                           SEMI-DETACHED DWELLING 
                                             241                                              172 
                             SEMI-DETACHED HOUSE                                SEMI-DETACHED SFD 
                                              56                                              155 
            SEMI-DETACHED SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING                                              SFD 
                                              90                                            26479 
                                  SFD - DETACHED                                   SFD - DETCAHED 
                                            3817                                               79 
                                  SFD - ROWHOUSE                                       SFD - SEMI 
                                              76                                              206 
                             SFD - SEMI DETACHED                              SFD - SEMI-DETACHED 
                                             353                                              209 
                              SFD - SEMIDETACHED                                  SFD - TOWNHOUSE 
                                             158                                              131 
                                         SFD DET                                     SFD DETACEHD 
                                             495                                               39 
                                    SFD DETACHED                                    SFD DETATCHED 
                                             755                                              231 
                                    SFD ROWHOUSE                                         SFD SEMI 
                                              31                                              857 
                               SFD SEMI DETACHED                                SFD SEMI-DETACHED 
                                              59                                              167 
                                   SFD TOWNHOUSE                                     SFD-DETACHED 
                                             155                                             8148 
                                   SFD-DETACHED                                      SFD-ROWHOUSE 
                                              37                                               56 
                                        SFD-SEMI                                SFD-SEMI DETACHED 
                                            1189                                              613 
                               SFD-SEMI-DETACHED                                    SFD-TOWNHOUSE 
                                             313                                              526 
                                         SINGLE                                     SINGLE FAMILY 
                                              41                                               64 
                          SINGLE FAMILY DETACHED                  SINGLE FAMILY DETACHED DWELLING 
                                            1615                                              222 
                    SINGLE FAMILY DETACHED HOUSE                           SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING 
                                              58                                             2673 
                     SINGLE FAMILY SEMI-DETACHED                     SINGLE-FAMILY DETACHED HOUSE 
                                              54                                              107 
               SINGLE-FAMILY SEMI-DETACHED HOUSE                                          STADIUM 
                                              53                                               37 
                               STUDENT RESIDENCE                                   SUBWAY STATION 
                                              34                                               44 
SURFACE PARKING LOT/EXISTING COMMERCIAL BUILDING                              TAKE OUT RESTAURANT 
                                              57                                               34 
                                         THEATRE                                        TOWNHOUSE 
                                              38                                              198 
                                 TOWNHOUSE - SFD                                       TOWNHOUSES 
                                              97                                               31 
                                 TRANSIT STATION                                          TRIPLEX 
                                              70                                               54 
                                   UNION STATION                                       UNIVERSITY 
                                              52                                              359 
                           UNIVERSITY OF TORONTO                                           VACANT 
                                              42                                            15010 
                                         VACANT                               VACANT (AFTER DEMO) 
                                              77                                               36 
                               VACANT COMMERCIAL                           VACANT COMMERCIAL UNIT 
                                              37                                               63 
                               VACANT INDUSTRIAL                                      VACANT LAND 
                                              32                                             1107 
                                      VACANT LOT                                    VACANT RETAIL 
                                             447                                              112 
                              VACANT RETAIL UNIT                   VACANT SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING  
                                              46                                               82 
                                    VACANT SPACE                                      VACANT UNIT 
                                             120                                              117 
                                           VACNT                                        WAREHOUSE 
                                              42                                              526 
                                WAREHOUSE/OFFICE                            WATER TREATMENT PLANT 
                                              54                                               46
```

> Apartment <- (ordered_use[6]+ ordered_use[7]+ ordered_use[8] + ordered_use[9] + ordered_use[10] + ordered_use[11] + ordered_use[12] + ordered_use[13] + ordered_use[14] + ordered_use[15] + ordered_use[16] + ordered_use[17] + ordered_use[30] + ordered_use[31] + ordered_use[33] + ordered_use[34] + ordered_use[35] + ordered_use[36] + ordered_use[37] + ordered_use[38] + ordered_use[39] + ordered_use[84] + ordered_use[85] + ordered_use[90] + ordered_use[91])

I am trying to convert anything that looks like an apartment,building,condo, unit and etc therefore I combined everything which looks similar but my question is, how can I replace those with my combined data of Apartment

Comment: Please correctly format your question. This is barely unreadable.

Comment: I am trying to convert anything that looks like an apartment (or apt.) build- ing or unit, or condo, into a common code "Apartment" so I combined anything looks like an apartment but my question is how can I replace the Apartment into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something to work with I pasted your text into the space between the quotes of:

```
 ordered_use <- read.fwf(textConnection("___"), widths=c(50,50), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And then trimmed blank-space and extracted every other row of the odd items and applied as.numeric to the even rows>

```
ordered_use[] <- lapply(ordered_use, trim)
ord2 <- data.frame(
   nams <- c( ordered_use[ c(TRUE,FALSE), "V1"], ordered_use[ c(TRUE,FALSE), "V2"]),
   nums=as.numeric(c( ordered_use[ c(FALSE,TRUE), "V1"], ordered_use[ c(FALSE,TRUE), "V2"]) )

> head(ord2)
                 nams  nums
1                     28706
2     2 UNIT DWELLING    99
3     3 UNIT DWELLING    31
4           APARTMENT    38
5  APARTMENT BUILDING  2042
6 APPARTMENT BUILDING    54
```

To extract items with "APT" or "CONDO" use `grepl`

```
> ord2[ grepl("APART|APPART|APT|CONDO", ord2$nams) , ]
                   nams nums
4             APARTMENT   38
5    APARTMENT BUILDING 2042
6   APPARTMENT BUILDING   54
7              APT BLDG   78
8                  APT.   41
9         APT. BUILDING   35
16          CONDOMINIUM   42
60    RESIDENTIAL CONDO   39
110           APARTMENT 4733
111      APARTMENT BLDG   37
112      APARTMENT UNIT   37
113                 APT  357
114        APT BUILDING   49
115           APT. BLDG   61
122               CONDO  223
```

I cannot tell whether your item numbers match up since you probably have a table object and I have two columns that are not arranges the same as yours.

```
> sum( ord2[ grepl("APART|APPART|APT|CONDO", ord2$nams) ,"nums" ])
[1] 7866
```

You should post the output of `dput(head(ordered_use, 20))` if you want an answer tailored to the type of object you have.

Comment: Error in read.fwf(textConnection("___", widths = c(50, 50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) : 
  argument "widths" is missing, with no default

Comment: it gives me this error when I try read.fwf(~

Comment: Error in ordered_use[c(TRUE, FALSE), "V1"] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: You were supposed to replace those underscores with the large amount of text, but I also failed to put in the closing parenthesis (which I will fix). In any event it would not have been expected to work on your `ordered_use` object anyway. It was jus my way of taking the text of the print output and creating something that could be worked on. You still should post what I suggested.